# difference in running with and without a rankfile

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I start my MPI program with `mpirun -np 23 -rf rankfile --hostfile hostfile ./mpi_testing` and it stalls, ie: it gets stuck, but when I start it with `mpirun -np 23 ./mpi_testing` it works perfectly fine. I am confident that there is nothing wrong with my rankfile or hostfile. Is there a problem specific to my MPI code or is there an external issue regarding mpirun in this case?

Update : I have 16 cores on the machine, and two sockets with eight cores each.

hostfile

```
localhost
```

rankfile

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0:0
rank 1=localhost slot=0:1
rank 2=localhost slot=0:2
rank 3=localhost slot=0:3
rank 4=localhost slot=0:4
rank 5=localhost slot=0:5
rank 6=localhost slot=0:6
rank 7=localhost slot=0:7
rank 8=localhost slot=1:0
rank 9=localhost slot=1:1
rank 10=localhost slot=1:2
rank 11=localhost slot=1:3
rank 12=localhost slot=1:4
rank 13=localhost slot=1:5
rank 14=localhost slot=1:6
rank 15=localhost slot=1:7
rank 16=localhost slot=0:1
rank 17=localhost slot=0:2
rank 18=localhost slot=0:3
rank 19=localhost slot=0:4
rank 20=localhost slot=0:5
rank 21=localhost slot=0:6
rank 22=localhost slot=0:7
```

Comment: I checked bindings with `--report-bindings` option, so that is correctly done

Comment: It is most likely a network issue. Running without `--hostfile` starts all processes on the localhost so no network issues are present. In any case, I doubt anyone could answer your question given the (lack of any) details provided.

Comment: I'm running it on localhost, so definitely not a networking issue. I just wanted to know if there is a generic issue, because according to my understanding the rankfile only maps processes to cores, and this is inconsequential regarding the running of the actual code.

Comment: Care to show the contents of `hostfile` and `rankfile`?